# Filtering in Realm database - findAll doesn't work for query containing boolean

Tags: android, filter, boolean, realm

I have a Realm database containing objects with one boolean attribute. Throughout the app I need to once filter through all content of the database, which works completely fine.

In another activity, I need to filter only through objects in database, which have the boolean value set to true. But it's not working, it still filter through ALL objects.

Can you check my code and try to tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

```
favourites = realm.where(MyObject.class).equalTo("isFavourite", true).findAll();

editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (favourites.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            adapter = new ImageAdapter(FavouritesActivity.this, helper.searchInFavourites(s));
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
}


OrderedRealmCollection<MyObject> searchInFavourites(CharSequence search) {
    OrderedRealmCollection<MyObject> favourites;
    if (search != null && search.length() > 0) {
        favourites = realm.where(MyObject.class).equalTo("isFavourite", true)
                .contains("name", search.toString(), Case.INSENSITIVE)
                .or()
                .contains("category", search.toString(), Case.INSENSITIVE)
                .or()
                .contains("description", search.toString(), Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
    } else {
        favourites = realm.where(Illusion.class).equalTo("isFavourite", true).findAll();
    }
    return favourites;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
favourites = realm.where(MyObject.class)
            .beginGroup() // <--
            .equalTo("isFavourite", true)
            .endGroup() // <--
            .beginGroup() // <--
            .contains("name", search.toString(), Case.INSENSITIVE)
            .or()
            .contains("category", search.toString(), Case.INSENSITIVE)
            .or()
            .contains("description", search.toString(), Case.INSENSITIVE)
            .endGroup() // <--
            .findAll();
```